# Is a server route the right way to do AJAX responses with Meteor/Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Still trying to get my footing with Meteor.  I need an AJAX like method to trigger something on the server and get a response back that it was done.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  // Remove Blog Posting
  this.route('blogRemove', {
    path: '/blogRemove/:_id',
    where: 'server',
    handler: function() {
        var request = this.request;
        var response = this.response;
        // Do some deleting here
      }
  });
});
```

This would trigger some server call to remove the blog with the given `_id`.  I would then reply with JSON via the `response` object.  But after 15yrs of development work I have learned: Just because it's possible, doesn't mean it's the right way...

So, the question is: For AJAX-type calls, is this the preferred way to do them in Meteor/Iron Router, or is there some more efficient/elegant way to do them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use a [meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header) for that. For instance:

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  blogRemove: function (id) {
    // delete the blog
    return {status: "OK", msg: "removed blog " + id};
  }
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.call('blogRemove', id, function(err, result) { 
  console.log(result); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I am still struggling with the concept of client/server code and where/how it runs in Meteor.  Huge change in thought process from Java/Spring.